# how to lowercase URL paramater in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have to redirect `URL` with `Upper Case` parameter to `URL` with `Lower Case` parameter.

Since I don't have access to `httpd.config file`, help me with some pieces of lines to do it in `.htaccess file`.

For example:

```
www.domain.com/Whatsapp-For-Business-A-Beginners-Guide
```

to

```
www.domain.com/whatsapp-for-business-a-beginners-guide
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look into this question, I guess you will find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206786/using-apache-htaccess-file-to-change-url-to-lowercase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert to lowercase in a mod\_rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923658/convert-to-lowercase-in-a-mod-rewrite-rule)

Comment: I don't have access to httpd.config file. I need to make it happen in htaccess file itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity to use php:

You can do that. in the `.htaccess` (before actual `RewriteRule`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule [A-Z] /linkChange.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and in `linkChange.php` :

```
<?php 
    $link = $_GET['l'];
    $newlink = strtr($link," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    header("Location: http://www.exemple.com". $newlink,TRUE,301); exit;
?>
```