# Magento index.php issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url, lowercase

I have an issue with Magento index.php URL

Sometimes it runs from **Index.php** and sometimes it runs from **index.php**

Like this

https://www.example.com/Index.php/demo

https://www.example.com/index.php/demo

While this situation occurs it's leading me to 404.

I tried some code from **.htaccess** to force redirect to index.php but it is not working properly.

So, I need it run only from **index.php** I don't want to use **Index.php**

I also tried several examples which are available in **SO** but,

I have shared hosting so I can't make any changes server/vhost config files

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Apache htaccess file to change URL to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206786/using-apache-htaccess-file-to-change-url-to-lowercase)

Comment: @ObsidianAge my server is shared. so i can't make changes in server/vhost config files

Comment: Anything in logs? If it shared you should see something in cpanel or write to support.

Comment: Did you try to enable rewrites to hide index.php ???

Comment: @btek yes i tried it