# how can i redirect URL from /?s="value" to /?s="VALUE" uppercase by editing htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I convert URL value to uppercase by editing the `htaccess` file?

I want to convert:

```
domain.com/?s="value"
```

to

```
domain.com/?s="VALUE" uppercase
```

Comment: My question is, can't you just "handle" it in uppercase within your PHP? `$variable = 
strtoupper($_GET['s']);`   -- Unless you are doing this for purely aesthetic reasons ??

Comment: You need to define a rewrite map which can only be done in server/vhost config files, not in htaccess files. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206880/3849743

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap):

```
RewriteMap up int:toupper
```

When you are redirecting, you would be able to change the variable to uppercase:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.+)  
RewriteRule ^/$ /?s=${up:%1} [L,NC]
```